# NAO_Cross compile ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everybody,

I have already installed  ROS fuerte on my PC. I am able to communicate with my NAO via NAOIP. Now I would like to use ROS independently on my NAO. I was trying to cross compile
( NAO ATOM CPU) but since I have already have my work space and ...
The tutorial for cross compiling is confusing and ask you to install every thing from zero.

Do you know how can I cross compile without changing my setting ?
Since I am new in ROS I will appreciate if you help me in this case.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69298/nao_cross-compile-ros/) by [Mohsen 2013](https://answers.ros.org/users/5116/mohsen-2013/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS Aldebaran SIG is probably the best resource: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-aldebaran

There's a recent thread here which might be of interest to you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-aldebaran/1jYLArulGo8

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0